# webapp hosted on ubuntu server works really slow

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ubuntu

I'm hosting my app on Ubuntu 14.04 server and what bothers me is that it loads really slow. http://188.166.160.66/ is the link to my app as I don't have domain for it yet. Demo preview isn't impletented yet (also it's not going to use database so testing with it wouldn't give any usefull information), so feel free to login as: `Login: test Password: test1234`. After you login, at first it looks like angular isn't loaded properly and is displayed as html, after some time it disappears and then it finally shows properly (last time I checked it took it about 3 minutes to load everything). I'm using sqlite and from what I know it's designed to be used locally, but I thought that since it's just a showcase project it will be enough. While being logged in, it's possible to use the api http://188.166.160.66/api/cards that will return existing cards as json, which usually is instant.

Github:
https://github.com/ziombo/KISDNU

Comment: you have some issue to end the request - some code maybe cause that ? even if the events load fast, at the end the connection stay open.

Comment: Any idea what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: no, debug it step by step, see if also other modules loaded

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my problem was adding `proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;` to the nginx .conf file.